# How do I answer questions about my unemployment period?

Tags: work-experience

I had a period that I was unemployed due to being a caregiver for my grandmother.  I marked unemployed in the employer section like it stated but it wants me to fill out all fields.  I'm unsure how to answer those questions like the address and other fields marked with astericks.

Comment: Is this an automated web-form?

Comment: Simple _N/A_'s would suffice? What fields are they actually requiring you to complete?

Comment: How long a period? As you can see from the comments you need to [edit] lots more info into your question.

Comment: Very much related: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2535/should-one-mention-case-of-force-majeur-exceptional-circumstances-in-a-cv-resu

Comment: Honesty is the best policy, as per the answer of [How to explain gap in employment history](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84187/how-to-explain-gap-in-employment-history). I would see unemployment from taking care of family members as a good personality trait.

Comment: If it won;t take N/A, list your home address in the address fields. If you are applying for a programming or business analyst position, note in the interview that their application system has a bug for unemployed people by requiring data in fields that don't make sense if you are unemployed during the time period.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend not marking it as "unemployed".

Being unemployed carries a big stigma when it comes to job applications. If you were working as a personal caregiver (especially for a family member) then it is far preferable to put that down instead of "unemployed".

Comment: I'm saying, rather than saying "unemployed" saying "caregiver" (and provide some details).

Comment: Unless you're being paid to be a caregiver, it's not employment. And even if there's some kind of compensation, it's not your normal line of work. I think it would be harder to explain this as work.

Comment: I'm not sure there is much of a stigma on a gap anymore.   I have had a couple of occasions where there was a gap of a month or two which was easily explained that the previous contract had ended/had funding cut and they let all/most of the staff go.  It happened once with a one week notice.  Usually people didn't even ask.   I think if you are honest about it, they will understand.