# Will changing jobs because of a national economic crisis have a negative effect on my career?

Tags: job-change

Because of the crisis in my country, employers are no longer able to pay for employees. This has forced me to change my job twice before finishing 6 months with them.

I bet this may hurt my career. How can I overcome this and compensate for this weak point?

Comment: If you are talking about how best to show your job history on your resume/CV, the answers here may be of interest to you: [How can I improve a resume to avoid looking like a job-hopper](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-improve-a-resume-to-avoid-looking-like-a-job-hopper). As [Michael said](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/2301/26), there's nothing wrong with indicating on your resume/CV that the short term was due to situation beyond your control.  If you are asking about something else, please clarify. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, having a number of jobs over short period of time can be damaging to you career, but it doesn't have to be. You can look at it from a couple of perspectives.

**Employers perspective**

The employer may think that you are not able to have much medium to long term stamina for a job. You will have to explain in your interview about the economic situation. You will also have to be make it clear in your CV that you were force to change jobs due to your companies financial situation, and is not due to your own doing.

**Technical perspective**

By changing jobs frequently, you don't end up being a master of knowledge and you end up being a person whom skills are stale. You can keep up to date by volunteering at a non-profit organisation. Eg, If you are an accountant, volunteer to do their book-keeping. If you are a software developer, join in some open source project and contribute.

Good luck!

Comment: -1: *By changing jobs frequently, you don't end up being a master of knowledge and you end up being a person whom skills are stale.* - Huh? I was thinking precisely the opposite.

Comment: @JimG. I should have qualified that. If the different jobs that you take on are in different domains or uses different technologies, then your skills can become stale because you would only just touch the surface of it. To gain fluency in any technology or domain, I think that a period of at least 3 years is required, or at least the successful completion of a couple of projects.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assume that whenever there is wide spread economic crisis employers will understand the impact on job histories.

I would expect that auto workers in Detroit didn't have to spend much time explaining why they lost their job, and that other workers in Detroit didn't have a hard time explaining how the related job losses impacted teachers, hospitals, restaurants...

It can be be used to explain a gap in the work history, or a short job that only lasted a couple of months. Flipping burgers for 3 months does pay some bills, even though it doesn't help your programming skills.

While the news reports unemployment numbers, they sometimes mention the underemployment number's. Those are people who have to work part time, or in lower paying jobs because they have no other choice.

A non-perfect employment history in the economy the world has had the last few years is not something you need to worry about.

Comment: You bring up all good points.  Its important to be able to explain your work history, the important thing is do NOT make an excuses, but you need to have a story.  There is a difference between an excuse ("I couldn't find a job in my field so I collected unemployment for 6 months.") and a story ("I couldn't find a job in my field so I took some part-time work ...".  I admit collecting unemployment is a valid story at times, but you must be able to explain what happen, if there is something strange in your work history.

Comment: *You have to assume that whenever there is wide spread economic crisis employers will understand the impact on job histories.* - I think you would be amazed at how short lived memories are of these things.  As long as the impact is not pervasive (IE the norm rather than the unfortunate exception) in a few years they are going to forget about the economic collapse and want to know why.  It may be accepted in Greece but else where probably not so much.

Comment: well, I guess here in my country they will understand, but what worries me is outside, I mean if I traveled and searched job outside,

Answer (score 2):

Put this note by each job:

**Position ended due to company closing down.**

Closing down may not quite be true, but if they stop paying everyone due to being out of cash, it's now a company in name only.  At least until it gets further funding.

Just make sure that their website doesn't make them appear to still be in business, i.e. if it has recent content.

The main aim with items like this is to deflect questions with up-front honest information.

Answer (score 1):

### Find something!

Any job is better than no job especially while others are out of work.  Volunteer if you have to, so long as you have some experience to put on your resume.

In a few years this collapse will be forgotten as the one that happened in 1989 and 2001 are now.  Employers will respect if you continue to work but if you wait for things to get better it will not be respected.

Will employers understand?  Some will, some wont.  But you are not going to get credit for not working but you will get credit for continuing to work.  It is not really fair and not a situation of your making.  But how you react to that situation is what the employers will respect or not.