# Frequent job switches

Tags: careers, career-switch

I am in IT profession and have switched my job very frequently (maximum tenure 10 months others less than 10 months). If my future employer asks me the reason for a switch what convincing answers I should give? Would honesty be the best policy? I don't want to seem as a job hopper...

Comment: Why *did* you keep switching jobs? Answer that question and you have your answer.

Comment: first company shifted, second company had no work and third when i got it i got married n relocated..but this shoul b convincing..

Comment: @Sonali: I think that's convincing enough. People switch jobs frequently, it's nothing you need to be ashamed of really.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I improve a resume to avoid looking like a job-hopper?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-improve-a-resume-to-avoid-looking-like-a-job-hopper)

Comment: Im technical. I job hop alot. My 2 favorite reasons are 'they are moving jobs to India' or when on a government contract 'the company lost the contract'. seems to work just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If my future employer asks me the reason for a switch what convincing
>   answers I should give?

You should be honest about why you switched, but try to accent the positive aspects. Honesty is convincing. Optimism is convincing.

You might try something along the lines of "I know it looks unusual, but in each case there were strong reasons why I felt it was really important to leave sooner than I would have liked.", and then be prepared to tell the specifics about why you have left each former job.

Remember, the hiring company wants to be reassured that you won't leave them after just a few months. Companies invest a lot in bringing in new employees - salary, training, disruption in other workers' time, etc. I have hired many people over the years. Hiring is often a tedious, difficult process for a hiring manager. And I always want to make a wise investment in someone that will be around for the long haul, rather than someone who will be gone in less than a year.

Thus, you want to indicate to them that this time you plan to stick. Tell them what is different now (you are married now and settled in, have no plans to move, you are sure this company has plenty of work, etc). Tell them that one of the most important things to you for your next job, is one where you can stay a long time.

But only say all this if you actually mean it. If you really suspect that you might not be around for long, look for temp jobs instead. Continued short-term job hopping probably is not good for your reputation or your career. I know seeing many sort-term jobs on a resume is a major red flag for me when I'm hiring.

Good luck!

Comment: thanks a lot..actually am worried of this question more than the interview....:(