# Job hopping on Applications

Tags: resume, job-change, applications, employment-gaps

Ive had a decent work history up to October 2014, but since that time, I've had 3 jobs. All of them in call centers. I quit one hoping the next would be better, but they are all the same. One had excellent benefits, but I quit that one too.  I've established that a call center is not for me.

So now I'm unemployed and my job applications scream job hopper? I've only put relevant experience on my CV/Resume, but at some point I know I'm going to have to fill out an application that shows my entire work history.  Can you leave jobs off an application and just have an employment gap?

My background and credit are clean, but with 3 jobs in one year, I need advice on how to go about applying for jobs?  I want to be truthful and at least get an interview, but I feel that a complete employment history is hurting my chances?   Thank you

Comment: If you kept it off your CV what stops you from keeping it off the application? And if said application is far enough in the future, shouldn't that making not matter as much? Provided of course that the job-hopping has ceased

Comment: Welcome to The Workplace @Leah! Your question may be tackled here: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-improve-a-resume-to-avoid-looking-like-a-job-hopper?lq=1.

Answer (score 3):

First I would simply leave it off the job history profile you fill out.  If you don't list it on your resume, you should not list it when filling out a job application.

If you feel uncomfortable doing this, you could simply add a line to your resume

> Have done various short term work during the last year.

Don't elaborate further on your resume, and when asked about it during interviews, simply explain that you worked for call centers, but that the work wasn't very rewarding or steady.

I doubt anyone would consider this a strike against you as I would guess call centers have pretty high turn-over.  If the rest of your career shows years at companies, any good hiring manager will see that you did what you had to do to survive.

If you feel obligated to put these jobs on your application, make sure HR will be expecting it.  Don't get caught hiding information from HR before your first day.

Comment: Sanity check (for yjose of us who want to answer your question): what kind of positions are you targeting these days?

Answer (score 0):

In the end, It's all about how you present it if questioned in an Interview.

Spend some time thinking about WHY you went to call centers in the first place. Was it because of less than ideal employment prospects in your chosen field?
Maybe you had immediate needs that had to be met and call centers were one of the first options you came upon?

Did you gain ANY skills from this job that you might not have had in your last job?

The reason I say this is because I find "hustle" to be a great quality in any person. I would much rather hire someone who shows work ethic than someone who does the minimum to get by.

AVOID: Telling them you jumped ship seeking better benefits. Managers want to hire someone who will show loyalty, and stick around for a while despite the ups and downs.

DO: Frame your experiences as positive. Maybe you can talk up aspects of the job; dealing with difficult "customers", working long hours (maybe), etc.
Alternatively, consider your circumstances and accomplishments outside your call center job. Maybe you have a side hustle that offers value above your "day job" or your time raising a family/being a caretaker for a family member precluded you from taking a risk on a better option.

The main takeaway is that ANY JOB is better than NO JOB. Talk about them however you want (sell it v.s. downplay it), but don't leave a year of non-steady employment in your resume. That would be much more detrimental tha