# Company very abusive - how to hang in there 8 more weeks

Tags: work-environment

Online position, no coworkers abusing me. The company is huge, multinational, and weekly comes up with every abusive (although marginally legal) tactics to harass employees.

Right now, hanging on by a thread. Hoping to keep my sanity. This company is so abusive that with each new tactic, another wave of quit without notice happens, and yet the company comes up with more abusive tactics. The general belief amongst the US employees is that the company wants us to voluntarily quit so they can offshore the work to their division overseas.

Any suggestions on what I can say to myself to just hang in there for 8 more weeks. I really have to have a job for 8 more weeks.

Comment: Can you give us an example what they do?

Comment: The question will probably be closed as opinion based, but...

Just say to yourself that the longer you stay there, the more you're really annoying them. They'll hate the fact that you're still there and refusing to leave. Once you do leave, talk to an attorney about constructive dismissal (maybe even a class action will be running by then)

Comment: It might be more constructive for you to focus on the reason why you need to endure 8 more weeks. You cannot change the *company*, but you can change *your situation*.

Comment: What works for you won't work for others. This is too individual and personalised to really answer. [This question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/74450/how-can-you-discover-meaning-and-purpose-in-your-development-work-when-it-feels) may have some useful info though.

Comment: Sheryl, there is an edit in the review queue from an anonymous user which adds significant information to the question. If this is you, please log onto the account you used to create the question before making edits.

Comment: I must reject the suggested edit because I have no way to verify it is indeed the OP's situation.

Comment: I always tell myself that I can put up with anything for a short period of time, if there's something good waiting for me on the other end. 8 weeks goes by very quickly once you realize you don't have to put up with thing forever. Just think, in a few days you'll only have to tolerate this for 7 weeks! (Hopefully, you have a new job already lined up?)

Answer (score 3):

Just don't take anything personally or become passionate about it. Focus on your job and let the rest flow past. I've worked for totally insane people cheerfully, so long as I'm getting paid I couldn't care less. That's the attitude you need to cultivate for a couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

If you need the job for eight more weeks (I suppose you have some good reasons) then focus on that. Whatever way they use to harass you, remember they are not trying to harass you, but they are trying to make you hand in your resignation. It seems that they want *you* to resign instead of firing you, so you should realise that you are reasonably safe from being fired and act accordingly.

And obviously start looking for a new job immediately.