# Is it frowned upon to quit a second successive job after only a short amount of time in both positions?

Tags: software-industry, junior

In my career so far, I have had three jobs.

My first position, I was a data analyst for a software house. My second position, I was a software developer for another software house, but I stayed for a brief time.

For my current position,  I was hired as a developer for a non-software house. I have been there for just over three months. I am not sure whether I am enjoying this, and wondering whether I'm cut out to be a developer.

My experience level as a software developer is minimal, I self taught myself during my time as a data analyst.

Comment: You describe your own software development experience as "minimal" - sounds like your boss is giving you work in line with that assessment. Junior developers - especially fresh new entries to development - don't typically get given whole projects of their own after only a few months, until they've done the kind of work you say you've been given

Comment: Very related: [How will a history of job-hopping affect my career or job search?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59075/how-will-a-history-of-job-hopping-affect-my-career-or-job-search)

Answer (score 21):

Put simply: yes, it would be a major concern for anyone hiring you as a software developer. Being somewhat blunt, it looks like you don't have the skills to be a successful software developer. If your CV comes onto my desk, I'd probably reject it *if you were applying to be a software developer*.

On the other hand, if you were applying to be a data analyst, you can relatively easily explain away those two jobs:

> I thought I was interested in moving into a software development role, but I now realise that I'm not, so I'm looking for a data analyst job.

That says to me "they made a mistake, they realise they've made a mistake and they're now fixing it". That's OK, particularly for someone just starting out on their career.

Answer (score 7):

> Is it frown upon to quit a second successive job after only a short amount of time in both positions?

Yes it is, it doesn't show anything positive, all the connotations are negative.

Either you can't get on with the people

Can't do the work

Can't commit

3 times in two years is a red flag for an employer.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Consider the perspective of the hiring company. You have a vacant position that you need filled. To fill it, you need to advertise. You need to read CVs, interview people, and after they're hired, train them. All these things take time (and by extension, money). It should be clear therefore that as much as possible, you don't want to have to hire. You want the people you hire to stay until they retire.

If an applicant jumps between jobs, it's a red flag that in a few months' time she might leave too, and then you'd be right back where you started. What's the point then? You'd much rather higher someone who's genuinely interested in working for you and will stay on for longer.

If you must quit, do so quickly during the probation period. You can argue then that the job wasn't a good fit for you - that, after all, is why a probation period exists.

Answer (score 2):

I was originally largely self-taught - just a couple of short non-credit programming courses. A few months into my career I did not know enough to run a project. I worked at the tasks I was assigned, and meanwhile studied for a master's degree in computer science in the evenings, and a few years later I knew more.

If you do want a software development career I suggest a similar strategy. Your current employer seems to have work available that I would expect someone self-taught with only a few months experience to be able to do well. Meanwhile, see what you can do to improve your programming education.

If you don't want to be a software developer, the [prior answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/122096/19325) suggests a good approach.

Comment: I agree with this answer, but you wouldn't even necessarily need to go to night school if you've already landed a developer job. The employer hired you because they think you have potential to be a good developer, but fancy degree or not you are still a junior with little experience and need to work your way up by proving it to them. If you think you might still want to be a developer then give this job a year and do your tasks well and with a positive attitude. They'll probably start assigning you more interesting tasks if you do the newbie tasks well.

Comment: @Keiki "improving your programming education" does not necessarily have to mean going to night school. It was the right answer for me in the early 1970's working in London. There are many more options now that may be a better fit for the OP.