# Would it look unprofessional to leave a job too soon?

Tags: interviewing, resume, job-search, job-change

After several years freelancing as a designer, I took on a job at a local internet marketing company... it's nothing special, but I couldn't be picky at the time as I was on the brink of running out of money altogether.

The job is bearable but is far too corporate for my liking... the work doesn't challenge me and offers me nothing in terms of valuable experience.

Now that my finances are in better shape I wish to look for a new job fairly soon, at more of a creative / advertising agency. However I've only been at my current job for 3–4 months, I'd like to leave when I've only been there for 6–7 months.

I'm sure if I explain all of the above during an interview then I'll be fine... but what about when I'm actually looking for a job? Should I include my current role on my CV?

I'm concerned that they might see on my CV that I've only been at my current job for a few months and it will look like I can't hold a job down for any decent length of time, and refuse me an interview as a result.

Comment: Just one man's opinion: in your field, Design, nobody cares.  If anything, it's a positive that you offer a "loose, creative" background.  Definitely go for it, no problem.

Comment: see also [How can I improve a resume to avoid looking like a job-hopper?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1263/168)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I include my current role on my CV?
>
> I'm concerned that they might see on my CV that I've only been at my
>   current job for a few months and it will look like I can't hold a job
>   down for any decent length of time, and refuse me an interview as a
>   result.

You shouldn't lie on your CV. Interviewing companies may check your history and ask for recommendations from the past employers so it's better to be rejected at first than later.

You are interested in creative/advertising agencies. If you have good portfolio, track record to complete important tasks, which you can show, it may be more important than length of stay.

It also depends on your age - for younger candidates job hopping is more common while they find suitable position.