# How can I tailor my resume to avoid the appearance of job hopping?

Tags: software-industry, resume, career-development, united-states, job-hopping

I've had two back-to-back, one-year stints at different companies. I'm considering returning to the company I left one year ago, bringing my total to three jobs in three years.

Each change was initiated by particular circumstances that I can justify. I never left for a performance reason, and I'm relatively confident I could obtain a good reference from my former employers if it matters.

I've been talking to one of my former bosses and she seems receptive to bringing me back, likely with a promotion from my old role. I'm cautious though since I'm running the risk of being branded a job hopper in the long run.

If I take this job at my old company, is there some way to address this on my Resume/CV that will help avoid giving the appearance that I am a job hopper?

Comment: It's hard for us to judge if it'll be seen as job hopping; that's ultimately a value judgement by the people reading your CV.

Comment: Seen as job hopping according to whom? Your former employer? This seems to be quite opinion based to be objectively answerable. IMO, staying a year in a job and then changing is not job hopping (unless you do it frequently), *maybe* if you were there for less than 6 months then *some people* could consider it job hopping

Comment: @JoeStrazzere yeah basically my job there changed under my feet.  My boss (the one who's rehiring me) moved to a different department then I got moved to a role much different than what I was originally hired for and my new boss was not willing to support an internal transfer.  If I was rehired I would like to stay there for at least 4-5 years.

Comment: Should I take a job or not is off topic.  However we may be able to help you address the issue on your resume to reduce the chances of it being perceived that way.  I have edited your question to reflect that.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @IDrinkandIKnowThings Thanks! yeah I would hope people on the internet don't know enough about me to judge if I should take it or not.  My question was aimed at understanding the ramifications if I were to take. I think the edit makes sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I improve a resume to avoid looking like a job-hopper?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1263/how-can-i-improve-a-resume-to-avoid-looking-like-a-job-hopper)

Comment: Is the employer that you are looking to go back to one of the 3 jobs in 3 years? If so they would already be aware 1. that the time you have been away from them has not been long and 2. that you did not stay with them very long which proves they would already know of your employment history. If they are not one of the 3 I would explain that you have been trying to find a long term position and while you have learned a lot from each place you never felt those positions to be long term.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I'm cautious though since I'm running the risk of being branded a job
>   hopper in the long run.
>
> Is it seen as job hopping if I return to a former employer ?

As a hiring manager, I would consider 3 jobs in 3 years as job-hopping. It wouldn't matter if two of those hops were to the same company or not. But it might depend on what kind of job history you held before those 3 hops.

You get to decide how much you care. And of course if you do go back but then stay for 10 years or so, the earlier hopping won't matter as much.

> If I take this job at my old company, is there some way to address
>   this on my Resume/CV that will help avoid giving the appearance that I
>   am a job hopper?

Probably not.

Your resume/CV should just lay out the data and dates of your jobs. Explaining away the potential negatives is a job for your cover letter, or for you during interviews.

The concern from some hiring managers will be that since you left several jobs after a short stint, that you might do the same to them. You might want to find ways to quell those fears in your cover letter and interviews.

And as I indicated, being able to say "Well, I have been at my current company for 5 years" is a powerful argument why you no longer make a habit of job hopping.

Comment: The question has been edited, and I think your experience could add so great value to the new version.  Would you consider editing to address the new version.