# Should I add a month only employment in my CV

Tags: professionalism, software-industry, job-search, united-kingdom

I rushed into employment after I was made redundant which turned out to be a disaster because the job description posted, mentioned and the real work was totally different and it affected my health as well.

The job didn't last for a full month and ended at a 28 days and now I am back onto the market and recruiters want a full description of what happened, ending with "We will have a look around". I feel I am wasting my energy with them.

Should I mention it in my CV or not as prior to that job I was made redundant after 6.5 months. Will it make me look like a job hopper?

Comment: What was the job and how did it differ from the description? And what was your last prior employment?Same industry?

Comment: @MatthewGaiser so JD was .NET, I am front end developer and the title was given software engineer where PO wanted me to design (graphics), senior dev wanted me to work of UI library and deliver all 3 things on dates they thought was realistic. whereas my CV never said Graphic Designer or SE.

Comment: Do you mean recruiters working for a recruiting firm (3rd-party) or those working for the company you want to work for (internal)? 3rd-party recruiters that are worth working with are rare.

Comment: Related: [In a job interview, how do I explain why I was fired?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/17906) and [How can I improve a resume to avoid looking like a job-hopper?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/1263)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I was thinking of quitting but they were first to give me an unsatisfactory performance in probation period and from what I understand is I wanted to find more and more about a product I was gonna work on which irked them because like I said all 3 people were pulling me in different direction but yes my phobia and asthma was reason I was gonna put a notice too

Comment: Yes, leave the one month off (unless it's for a security clearance, if it's for a security clearance, you have to mention it)

Answer (score 4):

**Don't put it on your resume**

A resume is a marketing document. You wouldn't put in a sales brochure that the prior owner of a house left after only a month. Something should only go on the resume if it makes you look good.

Just leave it off. It will seem like you were unemployed for two months (assuming your prior job search took a month).

> Should I mention it in my CV or not as prior to that job I was made redundant after 6.5 months.

Certainly. Even better would be a not your fault reason why you were made redundant such as company bankruptcy or mass layoff or division sale.

Answer (score 1):

> The job didn't last for a full month and ended at a 28 days
>
> Should I mention it in my CV or not as prior to that job I was made
>   redundant after 6.5 months.

You can choose to leave anything you like off of your resume.

Just be prepared to explain what you have been doing for the past month without lying about it. Lies can be uncovered, and the hiring managers I know don't like to employ liars.

You'll need to weigh the relative benefits of being open and honest by including all of your jobs, versus having a more sparse CV by excluding one or more jobs.

Also consider that for some hiring managers you will appear to be deceitful while explaining any omissions.

If I were the hiring manager, I'd prefer to see all of your jobs on your CV. And when I asked you why your most recent jobs were so short, I'd prefer to hear a well-thought-out reason that didn't just blame others.

Comment: " I'd prefer to hear a well-thought-out reason that didn't just blame others." what would be the way to put it. I had asthma?

Comment: @flux (Assuming you left on reasonable terms, gave required notice and didn't just storm out one day): "It became clear quite quickly during my probationary period that the role & company & me weren't going to be a good fit so we mutually agreed to end my involvement at the end of the first month".

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it to your resume , because HR can see that you have experience even that for only a month / 28 days. The point is , if you put it to your resume , you must can explain what you are doing in that job for a month , and the most important thing : **Don't Lie** and it should be fine .